# Why does Geary close randomly when trying to read full-page?

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-mail

I opened Geary for the first time today.  Added 4 separate accounts.  Sometimes when I click on an email to read in full page, Geary closes/quits without notice.  I can't see a pattern to when it closes.  Is there a solution? I'm happy to provide more information if you let me know what will be helpful.

Comment: Try opening a terminal and running the command `sudo dmesg | grep geary`. What output is displayed? The problem might be related to [this bug in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/geary/+bug/1500115).

Comment: Here's what I get (nothing):
:~$ sudo dmesg | grep geary
:~$ (this line is blank; it returns immediately) I found another posting that sounds like the same problem. I reported to launchpad that I was having the same problem.
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/cant-delete-email-from-geary-using-my-gmail-account